# Classification of critical points for two variables -- determinant vs definiteness

Tags: hessian-matrix, stationary-point

In first year we were taught to classify stationary points using the determinant of the Hessian matrix -- which was procedural and simple enough.

In second year we were introduced to classifying them using eigenvalues and the positive-definiteness... of the Hessian matrix.

I currently see no need of introducing these if it's more complicated just for the same task of classifying stationary points.

Is this somewhat a more "formal" way of classifying stationary points or am I missing the point here?

Comment: By stationary point, are you talking about optimization / extrema / min & max in multivariable calculus, or are you referring to equilibrium points in dynamical systems?

Comment: @erfink I mean by optimization/extreme/min&max in multivariable calculus, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're discussing the classification of extrema in multivariable calculus, wherein we use the [second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test). The first note is that you didn't use just the determinant of the Hessian matrix $H$! Classifying $\det(H)$ as positive / negative / zero was only one decision point in the algorithm. In effect, that algorithm guides you towards whether $H$ is positive definite / negative definite/ has both positive & negative eigenvalues without needing to discuss these terms (requires linear algebra knowledge from students).

In effect, you're doing the same thing, but now have the terminology of positive definite matrices.

> **Definition:** A square symmetric matrix $H$ is *positive definite* if $ \vec{x}^T H \vec{x} >0$ for any vector $\vec{x}\neq \vec{0}$.

You're currently using the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** $H$ is positive definite $\iff$ all eigenvalues of $H$ are positive ($\lambda_i >0$ for $\lambda_i$ an eigenvalue).

Whereas the "Intro to Multivariable Calculus w/o a lot of Linear Algebra" course relies on

> **Theorem ([Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)):** $H$ is positive definite $\iff$ all the upper-left determinants of $H$ are positive (these are also know as the *leading principal minors* of $H$). Alternatively, we can check all the lower-right determinants of $H$.

Notice that showing a critical point of $f(x,y)$ is a minimum using the second partial derivative test requires $\det(H(x_0, y_0))>0$ and $f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) >0$, which are precisely the upper-left determinants. Furthermore, $H$ is symmetric for all "reasonable" Intro to Multivariable Calculus problems due to Clairaut's Theorem ($f_{xy} = f_{yx}$ for nice functions).

#### Saddle points, inconclusive test

Furthermore, consider the other conclusions for the second derivative test on $f(x,y)$:

- ($\det(H) < 0 \implies$ saddle point). Since $\det(H)$ is the product of the eigenvalues, we necessarily have one positive and one negative eigenvalue and thus a saddle. Note that eigenvalues of a real matrix occur as complex conjugate pairs, thus if a $2 \times 2$ matrix has eigenvalues of $\alpha \pm i \beta$, we would have $\det(H) = (\alpha + i \beta)(\alpha - i \beta) = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 >0$.
- ($\det(H) = 0 \implies$ test fails). If $\det(H) =0$, then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $H$ as the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. Note that just knowing $0$ is an eigenvalue is insufficient to classify as a min/max/saddle (this is true for the general case as well). We could even still have a postive/negative *semi-definite* matrix. Regardless, we would need to look at even higher order terms in the Taylor series of $f(x,y)$...speaking of which...

#### Why is knowing that $H$ is positive definite enough?

For simplicity of notation, suppose that $(0,0)$ is a critical point of $f(x,y)$. There is a [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) for $f$ about $(0,0)$, letting all partial derivatives be evaluated at $(0,0)$:
\begin{align*} 
 f(x,y) &= f(0,0) + x f_x + y f_y + \frac{1}{2} \left[ x^2 f_{xx} + xy f_{xy} + yx f_{yx} + y^2 f_{yy} \right] + \cdots \\
 &= f(0,0) + (\nabla f )^T \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} + \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\ f_{yx} & f_{yy} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} +\cdots 
\end{align*}

However, we have that $\nabla f = \vec{0}$ since we're supposed to be at a critical point. Furthermore, the matrix of second partial derivatives is just the Hession matrix $H$. Letting $\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$, we can write 
\begin{align*} f(x,y) = f(\vec{x}) = f(0,0) + \frac{1}{2} \vec{x}^T H \vec{x} + \cdots .\end{align*}

Thus $H$ being positive definite is precisely the right thing to check for showing that $f(x,y) > f(0,0)$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and thus we have a local minimum at our critical point.

Comment: In effect, you still can! You will need to check the $n$ upper-left determinants for $H_{n \times n}$. Generally speaking, you get some bonus information by knowing the eigenvalues though.

Comment: Ahhh how did I not see that connection. So now I see that I couldn't have just used that "first-year" method for higher variable functions.
Another question - For your last theorem, why does the arrow not go the other way as well? If H is positive definite, shouldn't it mean all upper-left determinants of H are positive? 
edit: never mind, I posted too early. Thank you!!

Comment: Screwed up an edit; couldn't recall for a hot sec if we needed $H$ to be symmetric. Wikipedia says we don't

Comment: One more question -- for a 2x2 Hessian, if the determinant was negative regardless of the second derivative wrt x, then we conclude that the stationary point allows f to attain a saddle point.  

Relating this to the definiteness of the Hessian, then can we say that if D_k is less than zero for even k, then f has a saddle point? (where D_k denotes the determinant of the upper-left k x k sub-matrix)
What will we call this? (" H is something-definite")

Comment: Will edit to include that--excellent question.

Comment: Thank you for that.
My lecture notes say that if D_k < 0 for all odd k and D_k > 0 for all even k, then we have that H is negative-definite (i.e. the stationary point is a local max).
But what if I have a matrix with odd dimensions so we have D_k = det(H) for some odd k. If D_k < 0 we still have the matrix to be negative-definite (as per the definition in the notes) but with your definition, it means it's neither negative nor positive definite (hence stat. pt. is a saddle pt.)
Are my lecture notes technically wrong? Thank you

Comment: Nope, seems reasonable. Think of how taking the determinants $D_k$ would behave for $A=(-1)I$, which is negative definite.